# forever and hotnode can't run

Tags: node.js, forever

I install forver/hotnode through npm in ubuntu system ,but their can't  work properly.
as follows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nely1.png)

hope somebody can help me,thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-repo-nodejs-require-symlink-to-node-to-use-forever

Comment: thanks,ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs  /usr/sbin/node can solve this problem ,before it's wrong